# JS Regular Expression to Wrap All Characters in Span

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm needing to wrap all of the characters within a string inside of their own  tag. I've been able to do that with the following:

```
$(".text").html(function(index, html) {
   return html.replace(/(\w)/g, "<span>$&</span>");
});
```

This works, but I need it to also ignore any HTML tags. For example, this string:

```
'Text here<br>Text Here'
```

Currently it's ignoring the <>, but wrapping the "b" and "r" with span tags. Is it possible to ignore the entire html tag?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Instead of doing this to the entire `.text` element, find the nested elements and replace their text.

Answer (score 1):

You have a DOM parser literally at your fingertips, yet instead you choose [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)...

Doing it without jQuery because why do you even need jQuery for this?

```
function wrapEachLetter(textNode) {
    // Now you have only text, guaranteed!
    const html = "<span>"+textNode.nodeValue.split("").join("</span><span>")+"</span>";
    const tmp = document.createElement('ins');
    tmp.innerHTML = html;
    while(tmp.firstChild) textNode.parentNode.insertBefore(tmp.firstChild, textNode);
    textNode.remove();
}
document.querySelectorAll(".text").forEach(function recurse(root) {
    node.childNodes.forEach(node=>{
        switch( node.nodeType) {
        case Node.TEXT_NODE:
            wrapEachLetter(node);
            break;
        case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
            recurse(node);
            break;
        // leave any other node types as-is
        }
    });
});
```